# image mime type in winrt

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I need to figure out what mime type is the image my program downloaded from the web. I actually cannot find any solution that will work in windows store app.

thanks

Comment: I just download it from the web when i find it in <img src="..". I use HttpWebRequest to download.

Comment: i didn't try anything because i cannot find any acceptable solution. I found [WebImage class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage(v=vs.111).aspx) and there is this [MimeMapping class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160668.aspx) both are not in winRT

Comment: I need it for [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Comment: if you're using HttpWebRequest, doesn't the HttpWebResponse.Headers.ContentType have what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use the ContentType property of StorageFile.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.contenttype.aspx for more info.